# TypeScript says property does not exist on type but it clearly does

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the signup component:

```
import { type IResolveParams } from 'reactjs-social-login';
import { Box, Divider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { EmailSignupForm, type EmailSignupDataSchema } from './EmailSignupForm';
import { SocialSignups } from './SocialSignups';
import { SignupLoading } from './SignupLoading';

type SignupProvider = 'email' | 'facebook' | 'google' | 'linkedin';

type SignupData<T extends SignupProvider> = T extends 'email'
  ? {
      provider: 'email';
      data: EmailSignupDataSchema;
    }
  : IResolveParams;

type BackendError<T extends SignupProvider> = T extends 'email'
  ? {
      provider: 'email';
      errors: Partial<EmailSignupDataSchema>;
    }
  : {
      provider: Omit<SignupProvider, 'email'>;
      error: string;
    };

type SignupProps = {
  onSubmit: (data: SignupData<SignupProvider>) => void;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  backendError?: BackendError<SignupProvider>;
};

export const Signup = ({
  onSubmit,
  isLoading,
  backendError,
}: SignupProps): JSX.Element => {
  const onEmailSignupFormSubmit = (data: EmailSignupDataSchema): void => {
    onSubmit({
      provider: 'email',
      data,
    });
  };

  return (
    <Box
      minW={{ base: '90%', md: '468px' }}
      backgroundColor="whiteAlpha.900"
      boxShadow="md"
      px={5}
      py={8}
      position="relative"
    >
      {isLoading === true ? <SignupLoading /> : null}
      <EmailSignupForm
        onSubmit={onEmailSignupFormSubmit}
        backendError={
          backendError?.provider === 'email' ? backendError.errors : undefined
        }
      />
      <Divider />
      <SocialSignups
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        backendError={
          backendError?.error != null ? backendError.error : undefined
        }
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

and ts complaining that:

```
Property 'errors' does not exist on type '{ provider: "email"; errors: Partial<{ email: string; password: string; confirmPassword: string; captchaToken: string; }>; } | { provider: Omit<SignupProvider, "email">; error: string; }'.
  Property 'errors' does not exist on type '{ provider: Omit<SignupProvider, "email">; error: string; }'.
```

And for property 'error' it's the same.

What's happening there? It's clearly typed. What am I missing?

My understanding is that if BackendError has a provider 'email' it'll have the `errors` property, and if the provider is other then it'll have an `error` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type `BackendError` of the `backendError` destructured argument is a union type. So, Typescript cannot be certain if it is the type that contains the `error` property or the one that contains the `errors` property.

But *you are* checking if `provider === 'email'` before using `errors` and also you *are* checking the existence of `backendError?.error` before using it! This should be enough to determine the precise type of `backendError`, right?

Well yes, from my point of view. Clearly not from TS point of view. Apparently, for the first case, TS is confused by the fact that the `provider` can take either the value `'email'` for the type that contains `errors: Partial<EmailSignupDataSchema>`, or one of **several** other values for the type that contains `error: string`. If you had one type per possible value of the `provider`, this would work - just as in the [example of Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) in the documentation. **However, I do not know why TS does not understand your way**.

For the second case, testing the existence of a property with the `?.` results in this mistake apparently because using this operator demands the existence of the named property. It seems that the idiom of TS to check the existence of a property is the `in` operator; so changing your code to the following should work:

```
<SocialSignups
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  backendError={
    !!backendError && 'error' in backendError ? backendError.error : undefined
  }
/>
```

You can do the same for `errors` and be done with it:

```
<EmailSignupForm
  onSubmit={onEmailSignupFormSubmit}
  backendError={
    !!backendError && 'errors' in backendError ? backendError.errors : undefined
  }
/>
```

Or use a type predicate function:

```js
function isBackendErrorEmail(x?: BackendError<any>): x is {
    provider: 'email';
    errors: Partial<EmailSignupDataSchema>;
} {
    return !!x && x.provider === 'email';
}
```

And:

```
<EmailSignupForm
  onSubmit={onEmailSignupFormSubmit}
  backendError={
    isBackendErrorEmail(backendError) ? backendError.errors : undefined
  }
/>
```